# nan error in simple cuda based matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix, cuda, nan, multiplication

```
I started to write some simple cuda code recently. Please see my code below. 

#include "matrix_multiplication.h"

void MatMul(const Matrix A, const Matrix B, Matrix C)
{
  Matrix d_A;
  d_A.width = A.width;
  d_A.height = A.height;
  size_t size = A.width*A.height*sizeof(float);
  cudaError_t err = cudaMalloc(&d_A.elements,size);
  printf("CUDA malloc A: %s\n",cudaGetErrorString(err));
  err = cudaMemcpy(d_A.elements,A.elements,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  printf("Copy A to device: %s\n",cudaGetErrorString(err));

  Matrix d_B;
  d_B.width = B.width;
  d_B.height = B.height;
  size = B.width*B.height*sizeof(float);
  err = cudaMalloc(&d_B.elements,size);
  printf("CUDA malloc B: %s\n",cudaGetErrorString(err));
  err = cudaMemcpy(d_B.elements,B.elements,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  printf("Copy B to device: %s\n",cudaGetErrorString(err));

  Matrix d_C;
  d_C.width = C.width;
  d_C.height = C.height;
  size = C.width*C.height*sizeof(float);
  err = cudaMalloc(&d_C.elements,size);
  printf("CUDA malloc C: %s\n",cudaGetErrorString(err));

  dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
  dim3 dimGrid((B.width + dimBlock.x -1)/dimBlock.x,(A.height +
        dimBlock.y -1)/dimBlock.y);
  MatMulKernel<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(d_A,d_B,d_C);
  err = cudaThreadSynchronize();
  printf("Run kernel: %s\n",cudaGetErrorString(err));

  err =
    cudaMemcpy(C.elements,d_C.elements,size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  printf("Copy C off of device: %s\n",cudaGetErrorString(err));

  cudaFree(d_A.elements);
  cudaFree(d_B.elements);
  cudaFree(d_C.elements);
}

__global__ void MatMulKernel(Matrix A, Matrix B, Matrix C)
{
  float Cvalue = 0.0;
  int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
  int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

  if(row > A.height || col > B.width) return;

  for(int e = 0; e < A.width; ++e)
  {
    Cvalue +=(A.elements[row*A.width + e]) * (B.elements[e*B.width +
        col]);
  }
  C.elements[row*C.width + col] = Cvalue;
}
```

The results look like below (5 by 5 matrix), it sometimes contain nan or nonsense value in some elements.

2 1 2 0 0

nan 1 2 1 1

1 0 2 1 1

nan 0 2 1 0

3 1 4 2 1

I could not figure out the reason. Please help me with it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bound checks inside the kernel should be like this:

```
if(row >= A.height || col >= B.width) return;
```

Without the **=** sign, you were including (width + height - 1) extra threads into calculation which would perform out of bound memory access and cause undefined behavior.